# Login location doesn't seem to change

Tags: help, geoip

When I go to my email service it tells me from where I last logged in. It used to be different locations globally. Now it says A1 every time. Where is A1? Why isn't my login location server location changing? Could it be Telstra?

Answer (score 0):

Your email provider uses a so-called GeoIP database. In this list are IP addresses and their probable location saved. But Maxmind for instance tries to find out if an IP address is an anonymizer. Those IP get no specific country, but an [A1](http://dev.maxmind.com/faq/what-are-the-a1-anonymous-proxy-entries/). Thatswhy you probably see A1 everytime you log in via Tor.